# How to show numbers in datalables donut highchart

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I have a donut highchart where I am able to show name in data lables , but I need to show number in data lables . How can I achieve that ??

**My angular typescript donut highchart:-**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'shared-highcharts-donought',
  templateUrl: './highcharts-donought.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./highcharts-donought.component.scss']
})
export class HighchartsDonoughtComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  plotData: Array<object>;
  colorCodes = ['#f2bf5e', '#4bb0b8', '#536eb7'];
  @Input() chartID: string;
  @Input() set chartData(value: object) {
    this.modifyInput(value);
  }
  constructor() { }

  modifyInput(value) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      this.plotData = value.map((v: {label: string, value: string}, i) => {
        return {
          name: v.label,
          y: +v.value,
          color: this.colorCodes[i],
        };
      }, this);
      console.log('plot data looks like ', this.plotData);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartID);
  }

  renderChart(chartID) {
    highcharts.chart(chartID, {
      title: null,
      responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500,
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    layout: 'horizontal'

                }
            }
        }]
    },
      chart: {
        height: (9 / 13 * 100) + '%',
        type: 'pie',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          shadow: false,
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'hello',
        formatter: (val) => {
            return '<b>' + val['chart']['hoverPoint'].name + '</b><br/>: ' + val['chart']['hoverPoint'].percentage + ' %';
        }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Feedback',
      data: [...this.plotData
      ],
      size: '100%',
      innerSize: '40%',
      showInLegend: false,
      dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          crop: false,
      }
    }],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I want numbers (not percentage) in datalabels.

Stuck here for long. Isn't something I should do same as tooltip. I tried but not getting from where I will get value for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dataLabels.format`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.format) property to set the data label format. You could also add additional data to the string such as units. For more formatting options, you could refer [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting).

Try the following

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  crop: false,
  format: '{y}'
}
```

For more refined control over the format of the data labels, you could use [`dataLabels.formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.formatter).

Answer (score 0):

#### What about applying the value to the label before parsing data?

The idea is to end with:

```js
const name = `${data.label}: ${data.value}`;
```

Applied to your code would be:

```js
this.plotData = value.map((v: {label: string, value: string}, i) => {
  return {
    name: `${v.label}: ${v.value}`,
    y: +v.value,
    color: this.colorCodes[i],
  };
}, this);
```

Comment: What is data in `const name = ${data.label}: ${data.value};`